# Unobscured event gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add an Unobscured event to the root PhoneApplicationFrame like this:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual;
rootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler((s, e) => { doSomething(); });
```

But when I run the Windows Phone 8 app like this it gives me a NullReferenceException in the second line of that code sample.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is rootFrame null when you try to access Unobscured by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when you access `RootVisual` as it may still be null. For example, it will be null in your main page constructor. The `RootVisual` is set in `CompleteInitializePhoneApplication` method in your App.cs file.